# How do I use the inputs of 2 separate spinners

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm trying to build an app that takes 2 inputted redox pairs from 2 spinners to display information about the cell that could be made from these chemicals such as what would be used as the anode/cathode, the reduction potential of each half-reaction and the cell etc.

My issue is I haven't been able to find any way to take the input of both the spinners to be able to make the calculations, only have both spinners do the same thing.

My current code is this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
ArrayAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.pairs, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(MainActivity.this);

    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(MainActivity.this);
}



@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String choice1 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    double first = 0;
    double second = 0;
    double anode;
    double cathode;
    if (choice1 == getResources().getString(R.string.MnO4)){
        first = 0.60;
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), choice1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (choice1 == getResources().getString(R.string.Cl)) {
        first = 1.36;
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), choice1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (first > second) {
        cathode = first;
        anode = second;
    } else {
        cathode = second;
        anode = first;
    }
    double cellValue = anode - cathode;


}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

I'm very new to android studio so any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I don't know if it's the best practice, but what I'll do is declare local variables that I set values on each spinners onItemSelected callback. Like, spinner1 got variable1 and spinner2 got variable2

Comment: Why are you using the same adapter for both spinners?\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use anonymous classes to handle the `onItemSelected`. That way you can handle the selection of each `Spinner` independently.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.pairs, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Do what you need to do with spinner1 info
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });



    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Do what you need to do with spinner2 info
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
}
```

Now you can remove the Override method: 
@Override

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
```

and you can remove implements :

```
implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
```